# xcodebuild will codesign with Xcode 6 and alternate bundle ID but not with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, info.plist, codesign

Our CI server does a daily ad-hoc build of our app by swapping in a different bundle ID like this:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier com.example.app.daily" \
  app/app-Info.plist
```

and then building and archiving with xcodebuild:

```
xcodebuild \
  CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=YES \
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$DEVELOPER_NAME" \
  PROVISIONING_PROFILE="$PROFILE_UUID" \
  -sdk iphoneos \
  -workspace "$XCODE_WORKSPACE" \
  -scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME" \
  clean archive \
  -archivePath "$ARCHIVE_PATH"
```

with Xcode 6 this worked perfectly, but in Xcode 7 we're getting this error:

> Code Sign error: Provisioning profile does not match bundle
>   identifier: The provisioning profile specified in your build settings
>   (“Daily AdHoc Profile for CI Servers”) has an AppID of
>   “com.example.app.daily” which does not match your bundle
>   identifier “com.example.app”.

It's as if Xcode 7 isn't seeing that we changed the bundle ID. Is it looking somewhere else?

Comment: Hi. When I'm installed the `xcode7` and made a first build, xcode offered me to make upgrade project settings. After that the `BUNDLE_ID` was placed in the section `Packaging` in the build settings instead `Info-Plist.plist`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Mozilla pointed me in the right direction. Upgrading to an Xcode 7 project moved the bundle identifier into a "Product Bundle Identifier" setting in the Packaging section of the build settings.

Xcode's help sidebar revealed that this setting was named PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER. So my command became:

```
xcodebuild \
  CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=YES \
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$DEVELOPER_NAME" \
  PROVISIONING_PROFILE="$PROFILE_UUID" \
  PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER="com.example.app.daily" \
  -sdk iphoneos \
  -workspace "$XCODE_WORKSPACE" \
  -scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME" \
  clean archive \
  -archivePath "$ARCHIVE_PATH"
```

and it worked!